# Delegates and Events triggering on particular instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following class which defines an event and delegate. I then have a method which fires the event like this:

```
public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Create the delegate
    public delegate void ObjectDeath(GameObject go);
    // Create the event
    public static event ObjectDeath OnObjectDeath;

    public static void GiveDamage(GameObject dealer, GameObject receiver, float amount){
        /* 
            Subtract health here
            ... Code Snipped ...
        */
        if(objectHealth.health <= objectHealth.deathHealth){
            // Trigger the delegate/event
            OnObjectDeath(receiver);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have this class which listens for the event to get fired like this:

```
public class DeathListener : MonoBehaviour {

    // Add event listeners when object gets enabled
    void OnEnable () {
        HealthManager.OnObjectDeath += Died;
    }

    // Remove event listeners when object gets disabled
    void OnDisable () {
        HealthManager.OnObjectDeath -= Died;
    }

    void Died(GameObject go){
        if(gameObject == go){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

The question I have is, is it possible to fire the event on just particular objects?

So, instead of doing this:

```
// Trigger
OnObjectDeath(receiver);
// ---------------------------- //
void Died(GameObject go){
    if(gameObject == go){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

I can do something like this:

```
receiver.OnObjectDeath();
// ---------------------------- //
void Died(){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

I would like to have a way where in the event `Died` I don't have to check which object to apply it on. Currently if I remove the `if` statement, then it will apply that to all gameObjects not just the instance I am working with.

Comment: by saying "then it will apply that to all gameObjects not just the instance I am working with" do you mean all the objects in the scene ? even the ones that don't have the DeathListener  component ?

Comment: Sorry, no, just the ones that have the DeathListener component.

Comment: why did you made your event static ? please remove the static and see if it still destroys other gameObjects too

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be done: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/events?playlist=17117

Comment: your scenario is different , i posted an answer please consider it and see if it helps ...

Answer (score 5):

You seem to misuse the event pattern in your case. The point of event/listener is that the sender sends the info regardless of who is listening.

But in your case, the sender is aiming at one specific instance and you actually have a reference to it already. Then you might as well get the component of that object and call a method on it.

```
public static void GiveDamage(GameObject dealer, GameObject receiver, float amount){
   /* 
       Subtract health here
       ... Code Snipped ...
   */
   if(objectHealth.health <= objectHealth.deathHealth){
       // Trigger the delegate/event
       receiver.GetComponent< DeathListener >().Died(); // no need for parameter
    }
}
```

EDIT: Based on your comment, a more appropriate way (in my opinion) would be to have a IDamageable interface with Damage method. Then all items that should be damaged should implement the method so they get damaged properly. Then you can simply calls the Damage method with the amount of damage and it will take care of the death if needed.

Let's consider a bullet system:

```
public void Bullet:MonoBehaviour{
    public int damage = 10;
    // it is hitting either from raycast or collision or else
    void OnHit(GameObject collidedObject){
        IDamageable dam = collidedObject.GetComponent<IDamageable>();
        // if you hit a wall or no damageable item, it will be false
        if(dam != null) {
            dam.Damage(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

The bullet is oblivious to what it is hitting and should not care. Only matters how much it should damage.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour , IDamageable{
     int health = 20;
     public EventHandler <EventArgs> RaiseDeathEvent;
     protected void OnDeath(EventArgs arg){
          if(RaiseDeathEvent != null) RaiseDeathEvent(this, arg);
     }
     public void Damage(int damage){
         this.health -= damage;
         if(this.health < 0){
             Died();
             OnDeath(null);
         }
     }
}
```

There you go. If you need other items, like UI or scene manager to be informed of death so that they can perform an action, then you would get those to find the event and register to it. The player would not even know about them.

Comment: I am trying to get something similar to `instance.SendMessage("OnObjectDeath");`, which means that that won't work the way that I want it...

Comment: I also don't know if `DeathListener` is the component name or not. I could be called anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the static event because it will be shared across the HealthManager  class instances so i did this :

```
public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour {
// Create the delegate
public delegate void ObjectDeath(GameObject go);
// Create the event
public event ObjectDeath OnObjectDeath;
//this method must not be marked static also 
public void GiveDamage(GameObject dealer, GameObject receiver, float amount){
    /* 
        Subtract health here
        ... Code Snipped ...
    */
    if(objectHealth.health <= objectHealth.deathHealth){
        // Trigger the delegate/event
        OnObjectDeath();
    }
}
```

}

And in the DeathListener  class we have :

```
public class DeathListener : MonoBehaviour {
public HealthManager _hm;
void Awake(){
  _hm = GetComponent<HealthManager>();
}
// Add event listeners when object gets enabled
void OnEnable () {
    _hm.OnObjectDeath += Died;
}

// Remove event listeners when object gets disabled
void OnDisable () {
   _hm.OnObjectDeath -= Died;
}

void Died(){

        Destroy(gameObject);

} }
```

Now only the owner of each component will be destroyed separately not all of them together 
Please consider any syntax error in the code because i wrote this from your own partial code ...

Further note : you can even add a [RequireComponent (typeof (HealthManager))] to your DeathListener class so it can't be added without the healthmanager !